# iPhone ffmpeg dev using libav to decode from AMR to ACC codec

Tags: iphone, ffmpeg

It seems to be that, the AMR support of AudioQueue has been disappeared since iOS 4.3 was released. I can't use audio frame received from RSTP server with old way:

```
audioFormat.mFormatID = kAudioFormatAMR; 
int err = AudioQueueNewOutput(&audioFormat, MyAudioQueueOutputCallback, self, NULL, kCFRunLoopCommonModes, 0, &audioQueue);
```

As a result I received an error in last string.

Maybe someone know how to decode AMR AVPacket into raw buffer and encode it with AAC or MP3 using LIBAV?

I've tried to use

```
avcodec_decode_audio3
```

It works and I can get raw buffer but when I'm trying to encode it with

```
avcodec_encode_audio
```

I get 0 as result

This is my method to encode buffer:

```
- (AVPacket) encodeRawFrame:(const short *) in_buffer withSize:(unsigned int) in_buf_byte_size
{
    AVPacket res;
    AVCodec *codec;
    AVCodecContext *c= NULL;
    int count, out_size, outbuf_size, frame_byte_size;
    uint8_t *outbuf;

    avcodec_init();
    avcodec_register_all();

    printf("Audio encoding\n");

    codec = avcodec_find_encoder(CODEC_ID_AAC);
    if (!codec) {
        fprintf(stderr, "codec not found\n");
        return res;
    }

    c= avcodec_alloc_context();

    c->bit_rate = 64000;
    c->sample_rate = 24000;
    c->channels = 2;

    if (avcodec_open(c, codec) < 0) 
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "could not open codec\n");
    }
    else
    {
        frame_byte_size=c->frame_size*2*2;
        count = in_buf_byte_size/frame_byte_size;

        fprintf(stderr, "Number of frames: %d\n", count);

        outbuf_size = AVCODEC_MAX_AUDIO_FRAME_SIZE;
        outbuf = (uint8_t*) malloc(outbuf_size);

        out_size = avcodec_encode_audio(c, outbuf, outbuf_size, &in_buffer[frame_byte_size*i]);
        if(out_size >= 0)
        {
            res.size = outbuf_size;
            res.data = malloc(outbuf_size);                
        }

        free(outbuf);
    }


    avcodec_close(c);
    av_free(c);
    return res;
}
```

After encoding "out_size" is always 0 and result buffer is empty.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I've found all solutions and now my media player class can play RTSP audio and video. I understood that using decoding from AMR to AAC isn't a good idea because of resources usage and it would better to play RAW buffer which you can get using decoding means which allow get RAW buffer from AMR. I have a good sample (actually, I have to make small refactoring :) ) how to play RTSP streams and I'm ready to share it with ppl if they would mind providing emails :). Also, I have universal binary (armv6, armv7, i386) of LIBAV, AMR_NB and AAC encoder.

Thanks.

Comment: I am trying to play mms stream. Have successfully compiled libMMS and ffmpeg into my project. But I don't how to convert to mp3 or arc format that iPhone plays, from the buffer. Can you please provide sample code to convert wma to other formats?

Comment: Actually, I'm using camera stream and convert AMR format to RAW buffer and then play it as WAV format. It works just fine. iPhone supports AAC without any problems. I'm not sure if I can attache file to my response, because in my previous post I attachet a link to LIBAV binary to my Dropbox and moderators deleted it. If you can provide your email address then I can send you my player class to investigate it.